# Overriding Admin Login module

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, login

I have to requirement that magento front end contain admin login at the footer. I have done template. I need to redirect the page to admin credential checks controller after submitting admin username and password.. is their any idea,

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973134/magento-admin-login-through-curl

Answer (score 2):

Try to make your form submit to

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/dashboard/index');
```

There is not controller that handles the submission of the admin login form.
In the backend the login form has no action.

The login is handled by `Mage_Admin_Model_Observer::actionPreDispatchAdmin` this is the observer for the event `controller_action_predispatch` for the admin area.

Comment: Hey...give a reason for the downvotes. You don't like the answer....challenge it. Don't hit and run